# Internals of Dependency Property in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, dependency-properties

After reading [Internals of Dependeny Property in WPF](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/07/internals-of-dependency-property-in-wpf.html) I am wondering how Dependeny Properties are implemented in Silverlight for WP7. For the investigation Reflector and Dlls from [xda forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=647138) were used.

In WPF:

> A DependencyProperty maintains a static reference of all the
>   DependencyProperty you register in WPF object hierarchy. It maintains
>   a HashTable named PropertyFromName which it uses internally to get the
>   DependencyProperty object. So in other word, each dependencyProperty
>   object is registered in a global HashTable.

In Silverlight for WP7 DependencyProperties have almost the same global HashTable (actually it is

```
static Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, DependencyProperty>> _registeredProperties
```

)

But after looking through the source code of the *GetValue* and *SetValue* methods of the *DependencyObject* class I see that _*registeredProperties* is not used at all.

Does anybody know why it is implemented in such a way? Or maybe I've missed anything? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing something indeed. The `_registeredProperties` dictionary (and whichever equivalent it has in WPF) is used to retrieve a dependency property by its name. It's used mainly for the binding mechanism (where the framework has to retrieve the DP from an expression like `{Binding Path=PropertyName}`).

When you're in `GetValue` or `SetValue`, you already have a reference to the DP (it's the first parameter of the method). Therefore, `_registeredProperties` is useless there. `GetValue` and `SetValue` both use another dictionary, `_valueTable`, of type `Dictionary<DependencyProperty, EffectiveValueEntry>`. `_valueTable` is the actual collection associating a value to a DP.

Comment: You are right, @KooKiz. Thanks! Maybe you also know why values of CoreDependencyProperty are stored somewhere by using native call while values of CustomAttachedDependencyProperty and CustomDependencyProperty are stored inside the _valueTable field of the DependencyObject class?

Comment: Can't say for sure. It's probably because some controls, like the WebBrowser, are just wrappers around native controls. So it's probably easier for those controls to have native dependency properties.